# Kafka Connect: streaming changes from Postgres to topics using debezium

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm pretty new to Kafka and Kafka Connect world. I am trying to implement CDC using Kafka (on MSK), Kafka Connect (using the Debezium connector for PostgreSQL) and an RDS Postgres instance. Kafka Connect runs in a K8 pod in our cluster deployed in AWS.

Before diving into the details of the configuration used, I'll try to summarise the problem:

- Once the connector starts, it sends messages to the topic as expected (snahpshot)
- Once we make any change to a table (Create, Update, Delete), no messages are sent to the topic. We would expect to see messages about the changes made to the table.

My connector config looks like:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.dbname": "insights",
    "slot.name": "cdc_organization",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "column.blacklist": "password, access_key, reset_token",
    "database.server.name": "insights",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "plugin.name": "wal2json_rds_streaming",
    "schema.whitelist": "public",
    "table.whitelist": "public.kafka_connect_cdc_test",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "database.hostname": "de-test-sre-12373.cbplqnioxomr.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "database.password": "MYSECRETPWD",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "name": "source-postgres",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial"
}
```

We have tried different configurations for the `plugin.name` property: `wal2josn`, `wal2json_streaming` and `wal2json_rds_streaming`.

There's no problem of connection between the connector and the DB as we already saw messages flowing through as soon as the connector starts.

Is there a configuration issue with the connector described above that prevent us to see messages related to new changes appearing in the topic?

Thanks

Comment: Something useful in logs?

Comment: Not really, the only things we can see from the pod logs is: 
``
`[2021-07-09 09:18:06,632] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=source-postgres-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)`

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander we started to think that it might be related to how WAL is set up for our RDS Postgres instance. But the configs look fine so far

Comment: Why do you use `wal2json` plugin? not `pgoutput`?

Comment: Because we setup WAL on our postgres instance.

Comment: @AlessioG did you ever figure this out?  I'm getting the same "flushing 0 outstanding messages" output with no topic created, no messages in topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your connector config looks a bit confusing. I'm pretty new to Kafka as well so I don't really know the issue but this is my connector config that works for me.

```
{
   "name":"<connector_name>",
   "config": {
      "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
      "database.server.name":"<server>",
      "database.port":"5432",
      "database.hostname":"<host>",
      "database.user":"<user>",
      "database.dbname":"<password>",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "database.history.kafka.boostrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic":"<kafka_topic_name>",
      "plugin.name":"pgoutput",
      "include.schema.changes":"true"
   }
}
```

If this configuration didn't work aswell, try look up the log console; sometimes the error isn't the last write of the console

Comment: Sorry, what is confusing about it? I can clarify the points if it helps

Comment: I meant there are too many values that are "useless", try with this sample and then add what you need, table whitelist, ecc...